# Modx Wayfinder, using levelClass

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I'm trying to use &levelClass parametr of Wayfinder snippet of Modx. But it doesnt work. 
I have menu that contains of 3-4 levels, and each level has own class (like first level is "lvl1", second is "lvl2" and so on), and because of that I want to use levelClass, which promise to increment number of my class by 1 each new level.
Thats how I'm trying to call it:

```
[!Wayfinder? &startId=2  &rowTpl=lfRow &outerTpl=lfOuter &levelClass=lvl!]
```

But Wayfinder doesn't change  class and doesn't join CSS also. 
And I using Modx Evolution.
Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `levelClass` is available in the *Evolution* version of Wayfinder...

Since you're using custom templates, you'll need to manually add the `wf.classes` placeholder in your chunk, eg

```
<!-- lfRow chunk -->
<li[+wf.id+][+wf.classes+]> ...
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! but for some reason, my modx wayfinder works exactly as I wrote (without double-square-brackets and backticks). it's my second project, so no doubt(  in Internet, I saw a lot of examples as you told me, and few with my version.

Comment: to be sure I tested your advice and it didnt work. Menu dissapeared at all.

Comment: @Marla Are you sure you're using Revo?

Comment: oh, you are so right! I have Evo( yesterday re-installed it and downloaded the wrong version. Do you know what to do in this case with levelClass?

Comment: @Marla I've updated my answer however I'm not sure what parameters are even available in the Evo version. You should *really* consider using Revolution